# Float no DOMPDF não funciona como deveria

Tags: php, css, dompdf

Estou precisando usar o dmpdf para gerar uma grade de imagens, mas o float não funciona direito. Ao invés de ele descer quando chega no limite da página ele continua indo para a direita. Já tentei colocar uma div acima limitando o tamanho mas também não resolveu.

Basicamente, o código é esse:

```css
.imagem {
    height: 120px;
    float: left;
}
.imagem img {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem"><img src="http://www.devbattles.com/images/upload/php-elephant.png" /></div>
<div class="imagem"><img src="http://www.devbattles.com/images/upload/php-elephant.png" /></div>
<div class="imagem"><img src="http://www.devbattles.com/images/upload/php-elephant.png" /></div>
<div class="imagem"><img src="http://www.devbattles.com/images/upload/php-elephant.png" /></div>
<div class="imagem"><img src="http://www.devbattles.com/images/upload/php-elephant.png" /></div>
<div class="imagem"><img src="http://www.devbattles.com/images/upload/php-elephant.png" /></div>
<div class="imagem"><img src="http://www.devbattles.com/images/upload/php-elephant.png" /></div>
<div class="imagem"><img src="http://www.devbattles.com/images/upload/php-elephant.png" /></div>
```

PS: Já habilitei o define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", true);

Comment: É suposto as imagens se amontoarem umas por cima das outras cada vez que o ecrã se torna mais pequeno, é isso? Se for isso, ele atualmente já está a fazer isso, verifica aqui neste **[exemplo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8ehf9j3/)** que criei. Diminui o tamanho da janela do resultado para ver se é isso que estás a querer dizer ou fazer.

Comment: Na verdade não é ao reduzir a página que o problema ocorre. Estou gerando um pdf do tamanho A4, e ele continua do mesmo tamanho ao reduzir a tela. Porém as divs já aparecem sobrepostas. Deve ser algum bug do DOMPDF